# Skip DELETE rows in validation

Tags: python, django

I'm having problem on a custom inlineformset. I want validation to skip rows which have `delete checked`.

```
class TravelsRelationsForm(ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TravelsRelationsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
        instance = kwargs['instance']
    else:
        try:
            self.initial['title']
        except:
            self.initial[DELETION_FIELD_NAME] = True

# Force update of child
def has_changed(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return True

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    count = 0
    for form in self.forms:
        try:
            if not form.cleaned_data['DELETE']:
                count += 1
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    if count < 1:
        raise forms.ValidationError('You must have at least one title')

    return cleaned_data
```

At the same time I wan't to enforce at least one row. This doesn't work, because `TravelsRelationsForm' object has no attribute 'forms'`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal that you see this error. You have inlineformset logic in the modelform. You could replace your modelform clean() method with a full_clean() method:

```
def full_clean(self):
    if self.data.get('DELETE', False):
        # skip validation for form that has DELETE
        return

    # go through the normal validation process otherwise
    return super(TravelsRelationsForm, self).full_clean()
```

And such a formset validation:

```
raise forms.ValidationError('You must have at least one title')
```

Could be done directly in the view.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work... I still get all the empty rows marked as missing (with delete checked)

Comment: Actually the problem was that Django returns all the fields even if they are not required... they can be empty but they exist in the travelformset.errors...